# Itext PDF remove footer from existing pdf and create new pdf

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have an existing PDF and I need to remove the footer from the PDF on every page.

I fetch all pages from PDF but I am not able to remove the footer from the PDF.

I am using iText version 5.5.0.

```java
Document document = null;
PdfCopy writer = null;
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("input.pdf");
int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
outFile = "output.pdf";
document = new Document();
writer = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(outFile));
document.open();

for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {                               
    
    PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, j);
    writer.addPage(page);
}

document.close();
writer.close();
```

How can I remove the footer from this input.pdf file and create a new output.pdf file?

Answer (score 2):

You can use pdfSweep to delete text. See the example
https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/removing-content-with-pdfsweep

OR Check already given solutions

[How to remove headers and footers from PDF file using iText in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27884283/how-to-remove-headers-and-footers-from-pdf-file-using-itext-in-java)

[Issue in Removing Header and Footer in PDF using iText PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32448118/issue-in-removing-header-and-footer-in-pdf-using-itext-pdf)

[Remove Footer from PDF using IText5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580619/remove-footer-from-pdf-using-itext5-0)

My suggestion is to avoid creating a footer in the first place so that you can avoid recreating the pdf just for removing the footer

Answer (score 0):

### Using itextpdf lib crop the area and add header image
hope this will help

```
package com.ashok;

import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;

import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Locale;

public class ClipPdf {
    public static final String SRC = "/home/ashok/src-file.pdf";
    public static final String DEST = "/home/ashok/dest_new.pdf";
    public static final String imageFile = "/home/ashok/logo-1.jpeg";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        File file = new File(DEST);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        new ClipPdf().manipulatePdf(SRC, DEST);
    }

    /*
            Parameters:
        llx - lower left x // box size right
        lly - lower left y // box height up side
        urx - upper right x // box width
        ury - upper right y // box height down side
     */
    public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));

        int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
        PdfDictionary page;
        PdfArray media;
        //ImageData data = ImageDataFactory.create(imageFile);
       // Image img = new Image(data);
        com.itextpdf.text.Image image = com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance(imageFile);

/* Page wise */
        for (int p = 1; p <= n; p++) {
            page = reader.getPageN(p);
            media = page.getAsArray(PdfName.CROPBOX);
            if (media == null) {
                media = page.getAsArray(PdfName.MEDIABOX);
            }
/* CROP the area all 4 side */

            float llx = media.getAsNumber(0).floatValue() + 1; // footer
            float lly = media.getAsNumber(1).floatValue() + 100; // left side
            float w = media.getAsNumber(2).floatValue() - media.getAsNumber(0).floatValue() - 5; // right side
            float h = media.getAsNumber(3).floatValue() - media.getAsNumber(1).floatValue() - 210; // header
            String command = String.format(Locale.ROOT,
                    "\nq %.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f re W n\nq\n",
                    llx, lly, w, h);
            stamper.getUnderContent(p).setLiteral(command);
            stamper.getOverContent(p).setLiteral("\nQ\nQ\n");
            PdfContentByte content = stamper.getOverContent(p);

/* Add header image for example */   


            int indentation = 0;
            float scaler = (( reader.getPageSize(p).getWidth() -  reader.getPageSize(p).getBorderWidthLeft()
                    - reader.getPageSize(p).getBorderWidthRight() - indentation) / image.getWidth()) * 100;

            image.scalePercent(scaler);
            image.setAbsolutePosition(-5f, 760f);
            content.addImage(image);

        }
        stamper.close();
        reader.close();

    }
}
```